# Calculate the derivative of $F(t)=\int_0^tdz\int_0^zdy\int_0^y(y-z)^2f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> The original problem in the book is finding a way to prove that $$F(t)=\int_0^tdz\int_0^zdy\int_0^y(y-z)^2f(x)dx$$ has a derivative $\frac{dF}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^t(t-x)^3f(x)$.

I know how to get a $F(t)$ expressed without multi-integrals, which is, if I am right, $$F(t)=\int_0^t\frac{1}{12}(x-t)^4f(x)dx,$$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You can just do the integral and differentiate, it’s not hard.

Comment: yes I'm confused by these ts and xs. It's quite trivial actually. sorry for your time

Comment: No need to apologize. Every question is equally important, no matter how trivial.

Comment: If you are comfortable with chain rule, then the derivative is exactly like asking $\frac{d}{dt}F(a(t),b(t))$ where $$F(a,b) = \frac{1}{12}\int_0^a (x-b)^4f(x)dx$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Can you elaborate on this? I think the result of $\frac{d}{dt}F(a(t),b(t))$ is $$\frac{d}{dt}F(a(t),b(t))=\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}$$, right? So how do I calculate $\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}$ in this case?

Comment: The problem is not closed, I wrongly typed the expression of $F(t)$ and didn't thought too much on my first comment, it is now corrected so I cannot do the integral since $f$ is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You already did all the hard work, now just integrate :)

You get
$$
F(t) = \frac{1}{12} \left. \frac{(x-t)^5}{5} \right|_{x=0}^{x=t}
$$
Can you finish?